# `Fortran runtime error: File already opened in another unit` in Fortran OpenMP

Tags: fortran, openmp

I have a large data file which I need to write to multiple files of smaller size based on the data contained in each line. I want to write a parallel Fortran code for this to reduce time.

This is the nature of the large file

```
    1
    1
    2
    3
    1
    4
```

and I want to write all `1`s into one file, `2`'s into another so on.

This is the code I attempted

```
     program partest
     use omp_lib
     character*13 fn
     !$OMP PARALLEL private(fn)
     !$OMP DO
     do i=1,1000
       ii=10+omp_get_thread_num()
       jj=20+omp_get_thread_num()
       open(unit=ii,file='data.dat',status='old')
       write(fn,'(a,i4.4,a)') "file",i,'.dat'
       open(unit=jj,file=fn,status='unknown')
       do il=1,50000
           read(ii,*) j
           if (j .eq. i) then
             write(jj,*) j
           end if
       end do
       close(unit=ii)
       close(unit=jj)
    end do
    !$OMP END DO
    !$OMP END PARALLEL
    stop
    end
```

When I complied and run it gives an error

```
    At line 12 of file partest.f95 (unit = 11)
    Fortran runtime error: File already opened in another unit.
```

Can you please describe what is wrong here and how to fix that.
The serial code which does the job is

```
    program partest
    character*13 fn
     do i=1,1000
       open(unit=10,file='data.dat',status='old')
       write(fn,'(a,i4.4,a)') "file",i,'.dat'
       open(unit=11,file=fn,status='unknown')
       do il=1,50000
           read(10,*) j
           if (j .eq. i) then
             write(11,*) j
           end if
       end do
       close(unit=10)
       close(unit=11)
    end do
    stop
    end
```

I would like to make this code parallel so that (say if runs on 4 processors) multiple output files are simultaneously generated by multiple processors. I want the data (input) file to be read independently by each processor without concerning the other processors. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome. Your code is OpenMP, not MPI. OpenMP and MPI are two **completely** different things. Be sure to take the welcome [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Note that even after you fix your error, it is NOT worth making reading and writing parallel in this way. It will not make your program faster, it can likely make it slower, unless you have very special and expensive parallel hardware and filesystem.

Comment: Regarding your update, did you read my answer? Did you understand it? Are you missing something? What? Try to make those variables private, it is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You need several variables to be `private`. You presently have a race condition when several threads are writing and reading the same variable at the same time. These variables are: `ii`,`jj`,`j`. Maybe some more.

The error message is caused by opening file with the same unit number twice.

You can use the Fortran 2008 `newunit=` specifier instead of `unit=` and then you can remove the problematic computation

```
   ii=10+omp_get_thread_num()
   jj=20+omp_get_thread_num()
```

but still `ii` and `jj` must be `private`.

As I commented, it is not worth making your code parallel in this way. It will not be faster. See the comment under the question for more.

Comment: Try `ii=i` and `jj=i+1000`

Comment: I think `newunit` is better. Although I am not sure if the OP's compiler implements it threadsafe. But according to the Clerman and Spector book it should be fine. I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Agree, if `newunit` is possible, then it should be the first choice. A variant is `jj=ii + omp_get_num_threads()` otherwise. In any cases, these vrariables should definitely be private

Comment: If you do wish to have the file open in several threads, you will need open( action='read' ...) and you will not be able to write to it.  As mentioned above, plain Fortran intrinsics would not likely help with parallel performance.

Comment: @tim18 I am not sure what you mean by this comment. If you have a file opened once and access it from multiple threads in a synchronised manner, it should be completely fine, no matter if writing or reading.

Comment: The file access should be serialized if it is opened once with write permission and dealt with by multiple threads one at a time.  This should work fine, but no performance advantage expected.